# Сравнение двух разных массивов JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива которые нужно сравнить.

```js
var arr1 = document.querySelectorAll('#items p'); //Первый массив
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5] //Второй массив
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li><p>1</p></li>
  <li><p>2</p></li>
  <li><p>3</p></li>
  <li><p>4</p></li>
  <li><p>5</p></li>
</ul>
```

Нужно проверить совпадают ли значения параграфов с массивом, не получается вытащить значение p, поэтому не могу сравнить.

Одинаковые значения ввел для примера, значения подставляются все время разные.

Comment: Сравнить чтобы что?

Comment: Нужно проверить совпадают ли значения параграфов с массивом, не получается вытащить значение p, поэтому не могу сравнить

Comment: Одинаковые значения ввел для примера, значения подставляются все время разные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пример с полным соответствием:**

```js
var arr1 = document.querySelectorAll('#items p'); //Первый массив
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] //Второй массив

if (arr1.length === arr2.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (+arr1[i].textContent === arr2[i]) {
      console.log('Значение ' + arr1[i].textContent + ' в массиве arr1 равно значению ' + arr2[i].toString() + ' в массиве arr2')
    } else if (+arr1[i].textContent !== arr2[i]) {
      console.log('Значение ' + arr1[i].textContent + ' в массиве arr1 не равно значению ' + arr2[i].toString() + ' в массиве arr2');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li>
    <p>1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>5</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Пример с несоответствием элементов:**

```js
var arr1 = document.querySelectorAll('#items p'); //Первый массив
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] //Второй массив

if (arr1.length === arr2.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (+arr1[i].textContent === arr2[i]) {
      console.log('Значение ' + arr1[i].textContent + ' в массиве arr1 равно значению ' + arr2[i].toString() + ' в массиве arr2')
    } else if (+arr1[i].textContent !== arr2[i]) {
      console.log('Значение ' + arr1[i].textContent + ' в массиве arr1 не равно значению ' + arr2[i].toString() + ' в массиве arr2');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li>
    <p>1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>5</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*P.S. Так же можно сделать проверку на типы*

Comment: Все, спасибо большое Вам

Comment: @РинатАрифуллин, не за что, желаю успехов!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(ps, vals) {
  if (ps.length !== vals.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  for (var q=0; q<vals.length; ++q) {
    if (ps[q].textContent != vals[q]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(check(
  document.querySelectorAll('#items p'),
  [1,2,3,4,5]
));
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li><p>1</p></li>
  <li><p>2</p></li>
  <li><p>3</p></li>
  <li><p>4</p></li>
  <li><p>5</p></li>
</ul>
```